# Disable Matlab focus stealing, without modifying Matlab script

Tags: focus

I hava Matlab script running in the background. It keeps popping up pogress bar windows as the computation progresses. This is very annoying.

Problem is I did not write the Matlab script myself, and it is a very long and complicated piece of code that I don't want to mess with. So how can I prevent Matlab from stealing focus, without modifying the Matlab script? Hopefully some Ubuntu setting (I am running Xubuntu) will let me do this.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/23712424/855050. They are separate questions. Here I am asking for an Ubuntu setting. At SO I am asking for a Matlab setting.